# after loading new html content tooltip does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem with displaying a tooltip after loading new elements in a div.

My content loading code:

```
$ (Function () {
    
     $ ( '. Prop-next'). Click (function () {
         $ ('.props') .html ('<img src = "/ images / loading.gif" class = "loading" />')
         var p = parseInt ($ (this) .attr ('p')) + 3;
         $ (this) .attr ('p', p);
         $ .post ('/ lib / props.php', {p: p}, function (item) {
             $ ( '. Props'). Html (item);
         });
     });
});
```

when calling the .prop-next click element in the div .props new content appears, while the script does not work:

tooltip code:

```
var tooltips = document.querySelectorAll ('.tooltip');

window.onmousemove = function (e) {
     var x = (e.clientX - 350) + 'px',
         y = (e.clientY + 50) + 'px';
     for (var i = 0; i <tooltips.length; i ++) {
         tooltips [i] .style.top = y;
         tooltips [i] .style.left = x;
     }
};
```

Comment: there are multiple space (` `) characters in your query selectors and urls making this script impossible to work

Comment: Spaces were created when code was entered in the editor. I assure you that there are no spaces in the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code that binds mouse movement is done only once,, on page load, and that for consequence has that new items (the one that comes down the wire via AJAX) are not having that binging added.. instead of:

```
window.onmousemove = function (e) { // .. }
```

try so add dinamicly, or live hooking,, something like this should work:

```
$('body').on('mousemove', '.tooltip', function(e) {
  var x = (e.clientX - 350) + 'px',
    y = (e.clientY + 50) + 'px';
  for (var i = 0; i < tooltips.length; i++) {
    tooltips[i].style.top = y;
    tooltips[i].style.left = x;
  }
});
```

in this line: `$('body').on('mousemove', '.tooltip', ..` you define that your parent element (body) track mousemove only on `.tooltip` element, and that will track your new element that appear on page latter :)

Comment: The code you provided does not work. Pasted code: var tooltips = document.querySelectorAll('.tooltip');
    
    $('body').on('mousemove', '.tooltip', function(e) {
        var x = (e.clientX - 350) + 'px';
        var y = (e.clientY + 50) + 'px';
        for (var i = 0; i < tooltips.length; i++) {
            tooltips[i].style.top = y;
            tooltips[i].style.left = x;
        }
    });

Comment: try to 'alert' something to see if my code gets exec for new items or not

Comment: I removed the cache from the browser and the code works. Thank you :)